# XSLT namespace causing issue in foreach statement

Tags: xml, xslt

I've looked at a couple of different stackoverflow answers regarding this issue, but as I am new to this transformation topic, I feel like I have made a obvious mistake I simply cannot see.

Here is my `xml`

```
<application xmlns:os="http://url..." name="test">

<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title> Empire Burlesque </title>
    <artist> Bob Dylan </artist>
    <country> USA </country>
    <company> Columnbia </company>
  </cd>
</catalog>

</application>
```

Here is my `xsl`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UFT-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:os="http://url...">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding=ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="application">

<html>
<body>
  <h2>
    <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
  </h2>

  <!-- this doesn't work -->
  <xsl:for-each select="os:catalog/cd">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="title"></h2>
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="artist"></h2>
  </xsl:for-each>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is currently:

### Title Artist

But I want the output to be:

### Title Artist

### Empire Burlesque Bob Dylan

---

I'm not sure what the error is. I tried setting the template as `/` but that didn't seem to work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides missing a closing quote, `"os:catalog/cd` won't match because the `catalog` element is not in a namespace in your XML.  Change `xsl:for-each/@select` to `"catalog/cd"` to match the `catalog/cd` elements in your XML.

Understand that the declaration of a namespace prefix,

```
xmlns:os="http://url..."
```

does *not* imply that the namespace is actually used anywhere in the XML; in the case of your XML, it indeed is not.

Contrast this with a default namespace declaration,

```
xmlns="http://url..."
```

which automatically places the associated element and its descendents in the default namespace.

Comment: So if I were to remove the prefix, the `catalog/cd` would match since it "automatically places the associated element and its desendents in the default namespace"?

Comment: Removing the `os` prefix would allow `catalog/cd` to match because the `os` namespace prefix is declared but never used in your XML.  Your XML does not have a default namespace; it has a declaration for an unused namespace prefix.

Comment: So in the working version (I can't test it at the moment), it would be what I have, but every instance of the prefix `os` in both the `xml` and `xsl` file would be gone. Is this correct?

If so, can I change the template to match `/` (everything), or it must be `application`?

Comment: You seem to require more attention on this topic than is appropriate for the basic Q/A format of this site.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped, work further on your problem, and ask a new question if necessary.  Thanks.